# writing to an excel file only when certain conditions are fulfilled.. python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

```
person = Person()
```

#Fetching a person and then writing it to an excel file
#Need to write only if certain conditions are fulfilled

```
def fetchdata(idnumber):
    m = person.details(idnumber)
    name = m.name
    id =m.id
    known_for_department = m. known_for_department
    gender = m.gender
    if gender == 1:
        gender= "Female"
    elif gender== 2:
        gender= "Male"
    else:
        gender = "Not specified"
    place_of_birth = m.place_of_birth
    dob = m.birthday
    also_known_as = m.also_known_as
    print(f"{id} - {name} - {gender} ")
    data = [name, id, known_for_department, gender, place_of_birth, dob]
    for value in also_known_as:
        data.append(value)
    return data
```

Comment: The question doesn't look clear. What are the conditions you are looking at to be fulfilled for the excel to written?

Comment: if known_for_department is acting.. it should write